# Function ignoring parameter?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have VBA function in Access that should return the path of the special folder (MyDocuments, Desktop, etc) based on a string variable I passed it.  However, I'm always getting the public desktop "C:\Users\Public\Desktop" instead of what I pass in.  Here is the function code:

```
Function SpecialFolderPath(whichFolder As String) As String
    Debug.Print whichFolder

    Dim objWSHShell As Object
    Dim strSpecialFolderPath

    Set objWSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    SpecialFolderPath = objWSHShell.SpecialFolders(whichFolder)

    Debug.Print SpecialFolderPath

    Set objWSHShell = Nothing
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox "Error finding " & strSpecialFolder, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Function
```

So, no matter what I pass in as `whichFolder`, I always get `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`.   How can I correct this?

EDIT:

I'm calling this function in the following ways:
- `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "BoxForecasting_Jobs", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", SpecialFolderPath("MyDocuments") & "\BoxForecastByJobs.xlsx", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint`
-`Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(SpecialFolderPath("MyDocuments") & "\BoxForecastByJobs.xlsx")`

Comment: Is the correct path being printed via `Debug.Print()`?

Comment: I'm testing your code. Getting the same return as you.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling -No, Debig.Print() shows the same wrong value.

Comment: Can you add your calling code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
SpecialFolderPath = objWSHShell.SpecialFolders(whichFolder)
```

to:

```
SpecialFolderPath = objWSHShell.SpecialFolders("" & whichFolder & "")
```

I've tweaked your code a bit. Added `WhichFolder = "Templates"`, made it a sub and returned the result through a msgbox.

My end result:
[image]

Comment: You're feeding the function the name of the variable instead of the literal.

Comment: You're change does not affect anything for me. `objWSHShell.SpecialFolders(whichFolder)` with `whichFolder="MyDocuments"`is the same result as `objWSHShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")`

Comment: Yes it is. Just make sure the parameter you feed the function is a literal.

Answer (score 2):

It is a collection. See what's in it using a for each loop.

```
Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For each thing in wshshell.SpecialFolders 
    wscript.echo thing
Next
```

These are the names it accepts.

- AllUsersDesktop

  AllUsersStartMenu

  AllUsersPrograms

  AllUsersStartup

  Desktop

  Favorites

  Fonts

  MyDocuments

  NetHood

  PrintHood

  Programs

  Recent

  SendTo

  StartMenu

  Startup

  Templates